# synchronize system time in 2 phones

Tags: java, android, time, synchronization

I'm doing a research project in which 2 android phones have to play the same sound file at EXACTLY same time, to do this I need the system time in each phone are synchronized to millisecond. 
My question is that, how to achieve this on code level? Now all current methods can only do second-level synchronization.

Comment: I'm decently sure that even if you get the times synchronized using NTP or something, you'll have a tough time running your code on an exact millisecond in the VM.

Comment: By VM I mean the Dalvik Virtual Machine that android uses to execute Java code, not an android emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sync Time for Recording Data on Multiple Android Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190843/sync-time-for-recording-data-on-multiple-android-devices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.  If you need that, you need a real time OS, which Android isn't.  Too many things can make it go wrong-  clock skew, garbage collection, dalvik JIT differences, etc.  You can get close to it using the real time clock functions, but you're never going to get that kind of performance assured in anything written on top of a VM on a multi-tasking OS.

Comment: thank you, is there any other way to do that? My current idea is that first synchronize the system time, then send a message to these 2 phones via socket in which I specify when the sound file should be played.

Comment: @JunfeiWang You could have both devices listening for a message on a socket. Then send your message from a 3rd machine on the same network via Multi-Cast. Depending on network traffic conditions both should receive the message at roughly the same time (close enough that they should play the sound in sync enough that the human ear wouldn't notice the difference).

Comment: @FoamyGuy thank you for your advice, I will try to set up a dedicated wifi network and implement this.